# add usercontrol with buttons and texboxes in a string at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

i have a template with some tokens like %{login}% or %{menu}%

i have also the related user controls Login and menu

the html string template comes from the db, my problem is that if i render the usercontrols with the Page.RenderControl or Server.Execute methods, i obviusly take the error "texbox/button must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server"

the login and menu usercontrols have inside the asp.net controls, so, how can i replace my tokens programmatically with the usercontrols leaving working the asp.net controls functionalities in the login and the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, you could read your string, and translate the tokens to the appropriate controls (which you probably already do), and, in so doing, you would instantiate an instance of your control and add it to an existing control collection, most commonly a PlaceHolder control.

Here's some reading on the topic: [Dynamic Controls in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131055/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx)